# Why was rAmAnuja refused initiation for 17 times?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, guru, ramanujacharya, initiation

In my previous question, I have talked about him doing the mass initiation against the orders of his guru but this question is related to his own initiation.

He approached Thiurukottiyur Nambi for initiation into Vaishnava mantra. But he was refused not once or twice but for **17 times!**.

Usually, traditional gurus do not refuse genuine seekers.

So on what grounds was rAmAnuja not given the mantra so many times?

Was he considered unfit for the sacred mantra?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72082/discussion-on-question-by-rakesh-joshi-why-was-ramanuja-refused-initiation-for-1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story of Ramanuja being initiated into the Vaishnava Mantra after being turned down by Thirukkottiyar Nambi 17 times is well-known. Ramanuja never understood the reason for the refusal and was deeply disappointed for not able to receive the mantra.

It is said that Ramanuja was denied the sacred mantra because he was identifying himself as Ramanuja, but not as the servant of Lord Varadaraja. Otherwise, he was not considered unfit for the sacred mantra.

You can read more about it at http://www.mypanchang.com/ramanuja.php